# Javascript 'undefined error' in asp.net webform

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm not a javascript expert, but I've used it before, and this problem is perplexing me.  Here's the javascript:

```
function formatNumThousands(myNumber) {
    if (myNumber.length > 0) {
        var index = myNumber.indexOf(',');
        while (index != -1) {
             myNumber = myNumber.replace(',', '');
             index = myNumber.indexOf(',');
        }
        var myResult = '';
        for (var i = myNumber.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            myResult = myNumber[i] + myResult;
            if ((myNumber.length - i) % 3 == 0 & i > 0) myResult = ',' + myResult;
        }
        document.getElementById('<%=txtMyNumber.ClientID%>').value = myResult;
     }
  }
```

In the code behind, I set the attribute for this text box's OnBlur event:

```
this.txtMyNumber.Attributes.Add("onblur", "formatNumThousands(this.value);");
```

I build and publish the app and it runs fine on my machine.  Two other users get 'undefined' in the text box, regardless of what they do.

Comment: Can you get a more specific error from your users, possibly the line number? The code executed fine for me (chrome 11) - http://jsfiddle.net/x4bC6/

Comment: @Quintin's jsFiddle worked fine for me in Chrome and IE8 too.

Comment: Tweaked version of Quintin's jsfiddle to make it a little more generic here  http://jsfiddle.net/zERNC/

Answer (score 0):

Try this trimmed version ([see in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4bC6/4/)). See that I replaced the `[]` operator for the `charAt()` method, as it's a more conservative approach for extracting individual characters from a string:

```
function formatNumThousands(editElement) {
    if (!editElement || editElement.value.length == 0)
        return;

    var myNumber = editElement.value.replace(/,/g, '');

    var myResult = '';
    for (var i = myNumber.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        myResult = myNumber.charAt(i) + myResult;
        if ((myNumber.length - i) % 3 == 0 & i > 0)
            myResult = ',' + myResult;
    }

    editElement.value = myResult;
}
```

Don't forget to change the code behind to

```
// Notice that `.value´ is gone:
this.txtMyNumber.Attributes.Add("onblur", "formatNumThousands(this)");
```

Comment: Ok, sorry for the EXTREME delay in getting to this, but I've been in California on vacation (that's a big deal in my house, located in the central Ohio area!).  Anyway, I have determined that my user's errors occur because myNumber[i] in the for loop is undefined.  What I don't understand is why the var isn't implicitly cast to an array, as it seems, and why it is on many machines -- like the jsfuddle example provided by @Quintin Robinson, tweaked by @Bala R.  Thanks for help so far, I hope the added details might provide an 'aha' for someone.

Comment: @Ron, I think it's a good idea to try to use the `charAt()` method instead of the `[]` operator. See the edited answer above.